# Powershell random color change

Tags: powershell, random, colors

Never used Powershell before and im trying to recreate the following Bash script in powershell:

**while true; do head -c200 /dev/urandom | od -An -w50 -x | grep -E --color "([[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]){2}"; sleep 0.5; done**

Here's what i got, but i want it to turn random lines into red, rather than every five instances;

```
while(Get-Random)
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
    Write-Host -NoNewline "   " (get-random) 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 30    
    Write-Host -NoNewline "   " (get-random) 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
    Write-Host -NoNewline "   " (get-random) 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 30    
    Write-Host -NoNewline "   " (get-random) 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
    Write-Host -NoNewline "   " (get-random) -ForegroundColor red
}
```

Any idea how i can go about setting "-ForegroundColor red" for random lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$color=@('gray','red')
while(Get-Random)
{   Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
    Write-Host -NoNewline "   " (get-random) -ForegroundColor (Get-random $color)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Now, lets see how much i can push my luck - How can i get it to display as a nice clean grid?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore - please define "nice, clean grid" ... [*grin*]

Comment: This gives a nice clean grid, but not sure if this is your what you are after ;)
`Write-Host -NoNewline "   " (1000..9999 | get-random) -ForegroundColor (Get-random $color)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey
Really, im just trying to convert the aforementioned bash script into Power Shell.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore - yep, but many of us don't have the ability to run that bash code ... so we have no idea what it will look like.

Comment: Just thought I'd leave a note here, you can randomly get a color name like this: `Get-Random ([System.ConsoleColor].GetEnumNames())`

Comment: Another option being to just generate a number between 0 and 15 (inclusive). Or 1 and 15 to exclude black `Get-Random -Min 1 -Max 15`